# Render a HTML File in a components html which contains multiple web components

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a component that contains some functions and a "default" layout. It looks something like this:

```html
<a routerLink="/some-link">
  <button class="btn white black-text">Button Text</button>
</a>

<h2>Some Text</h2>

<div [innerHTML]="data"></div>

<a routerLink="/some-other-link">
  <button class="btn white black-text">Button Text</button>
</a>
```

The `innerHTML` data get filled like this:

```js
export class SingleComponent {
  public data: SafeHtml;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private route: ActivatedRoute,
              public functionService: FunctionService, private _sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe((paramMap) => {
      const id = paramMap.get('id');
      this.http
        .get('assets/data/' + id + '/data.html', {responseType: 'text'})
        .subscribe((data) => this.data= this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(data));
    });
  }
}
```

Now this alone works, but the tricky thing is that the `data.html` contains web components, some with `@Ouputs` and also it wants to use functions from that `FunctionService`. And that does not work. I could also put these functions in the `SingleComponent` and use these instead, but the issue still remains.

Here is a sample of what's to load from the data.html:

```html
<div> some text </div>

<some-component-1 [input]="'text'"></some-component-1>

<div> some text </div>

<some-component-2 [input]="'text'" (output)="functionService.doStuff()"></some-component-2>
```

I've already searched for answers but the only thing I could find was the `DynamicComponentLoader`. But from my understanding that can only load specific components in the `innerHTML`, which is not what I want.
https://medium.com/acute-angular/angular-how-to-render-html-containing-angular-components-dynamically-at-run-time-ee8fc907b545

My plan is to have **thousands** of these `data.html`s but load them all over this `SingleComponent`. That way I don't need to register thousands of full components for only having the HTML.

Anyone an idea on how to do this?

**Update:**
I've searched a bit longer now. I've managed to load the components itself, but not with it's in- or outputs. The majority of people online says that unfurtunately it's not possible to anyhow render a HTML with components and make them fully functional. That means: for now the only way for me to achieve this is by creating duplicates of the "SingleComponent" and instead of parseing my HTML data write it into the component HTML directly and basically have not DRY code duplicates...
I hope angular will find a way to achieve this in the future.